# Seek utility that formats html code

Tags: html, utilities

I'm inheriting a mess of a website where the structure of  is impossible to follow mostly because of lack of indenting. Is there a utility that can massage existing code to proper indents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is pretty much the standard, and it's often already integrated into text editors and IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) does a great job at reformatting. It has options for tuning how it processes the files.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana has a source code formatter, it works for HTML, Javascript, PHP, CSS, pretty much everything a web-geek needs ...